# How do I deselect hidden items with python

Tags: python, selection-tools

I'm making a script that will hide collision meshes marked with "UCX_" but it doesn't work when I have a selected but hidden item. The problem is that it doesn't deselect the items it hides and I cant run

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

because Blender doesn't consider it selected even though its highlighted in blue

[image: Outliner showing hidden but still selected item]

Is there some context that I'm missing or how should I go about deselecting the items in the outliner?

**Edit:** Following Gorgious advice I added a deselect in the for loop:

```
obj.select_set(False)
```

The problem persisted with Blender still having an "implied" (not sure about the nomenclature) selection which disables further use of the script. The streamable link illustrates the problem I'm currently having:
https://streamable.com/75622d
[image]

Comment: It's confusing but outliner selection and 3D viewport selection are not always synced. A hidden object is automatically removed from the `bpy.context.selected_objects` container. You can unselect an object without an operator with `obj.select_set(False)` see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/156898/86891

Comment: Thanks for the link, it did mostly work although Blender still has an "implied" selection and if I have a collision mesh selected when activating the script it'll still be sort of selected. Image in the edit shows what I mean. I can't run the script again since its now greyed out.

Comment: Yeah for some reason, despite being unselected it is still considered as the active object. :) You can clear the active object with `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = None`

Comment: Ah nice, that works, thanks for taking the time to help!